# Best practice for selecting which Redis server to read in real time

Tags: nginx, redis, hash

I have a nginx server that has a redis master and two salves of the master.  The slaves are read and the master is read and write.  Nginx server is fastcgi using spawed python apps and using pyredis.

When is comes for a read from my nginx app, what is best practice for determining which server gets the read among the three? Is it determined in realtime? Do I just do simple random selection using round robin in real time?

Again, I just have on master.  Soon I will have two and will use consistent hashing in python using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hash_ring so select which server gets the keys.

For the interim, is it wise to select which server will get the read using the hash ring even though they should be exact copies?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is abstract the code that does that so it doesn't change your app logic later when you split the data.
and as for reading - I'd use just the slaves for that. you can use the hashing if you want, provided it doesn't affect your code and is abstracted.